# Is there any way we can extract the decision rules from the random forest output of sparkR setting numTree=1 as parameter?

Tags: r, sparkr

I actually am trying to extract decision tree from sparkR random forest.  The onlye way I could find was to save the summary(model) output in a file in text format and then parse it. Is there an easier way to get it?